# Getting correct intervals on datetime x-axis in Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have the code below to plot a stacked bar chart. How should one deal correctly with the datetime format in the `dates` list and with the x-axis to get a spacing between the x-ticks that corresponds to linear time?

```
dates = ['2018-01-25 13:04:59',
 '2018-01-26 06:16:23',
 '2018-01-26 11:03:12',
 '2018-01-26 14:10:33']

animals = ["pig", "cow", "ape"]

colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

data = {'dates' : dates,
        'pig'   : [2, 1, 4, 3],
        'cow'   : [5, 3, 4, 2],
        'ape'   : [3, 2, 4, 4]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=dates, plot_height=350)

p.vbar_stack(animals, x='dates', width=0.9, color=colors, source=source,
             legend=[value(x) for x in animals])
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to accomplish. I can't tell e.g. if you just want to format the existing ticks differently, or you want different tick locations altogether. Also "linear time" is not meaningful or descriptive, what does that mean in this context?

Comment: Instead of having one xtick for each existing timestamp in `dates`, I want the x-axis to have an even spacing between days/hours/minutes/seconds, and to plot data for the `dates` on the corresponding position on x.

Answer (score 0):

Hoi,

If I understand you correctly, this is actually not very difficult to realize:

First thing you need to do is to convert your timestamps to something you can plot, so the first timestamp could be 0 and the next one should be the amount of seconds since then and so on. To do this you can convert it to datetime to work with in Python:

```
import datetime
def conv_time(time):
   return(datetime.datetime.strptime(time , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

With this you can convert your list of times to datetimes:

```
dates = ['2018-01-25 13:04:59', '2018-01-26 06:16:23',
         '2018-01-26 11:03:12', '2018-01-26 14:10:33']
dates = [conv_time(i) for i in dates]
```

And calculate the number of seconds since the first timestamp:

```
dates = [conv_time(i) for i in dates]
start = dates[0]
seconds = [(i - start).total_seconds() for i in dates]
```

Resulting in:

```
[0.0, 61884.0, 79093.0, 90334.0]
```

you can plot on your axis. (alternatively you can also use minutes or hours.

Cheers,
Sebastian